# How to solve with statuses/update Code 403 => Error 220 ,Your credentials do not allow access to this resource

Tags: http, twitter, oauth-2.0

My code was working will with all the functionality of post tweet, Get follower.
but for the last two days with posting a tweet I got the following error:

I treid alot of ways and it still t same problem.

```
  public function old_old_postTweet($text){

        $this -> init();
        $return = $this-> twitter -> sendTweet($text);

        return $return;
    }
```

the first function were worked before without any problems.

```
 public function curl_postTweet($text){

        $cmd = "curl --request 'POST' 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json' --data 'status=Maybe+he%27ll+finally+find+his+keys.+%23peterfalk' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"nTNu3BXXXXXXXXbKP2ruA\", oauth_nonce=\"8aff955397bXXXXXXXX940cc6ded24\", oauth_signature=\"X8%2B%2FOXXX5wm%2BgXXXXXKgxlu6o%3D\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1395641319\", oauth_token=\"2336351089-5zSK2ElXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCIrz0v12ba33\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"' --verbose";
        $return = shell_exec($cmd);

        return $return;
    }
```

this curl command I got it for the dev.twitter console and it's work in the terminal.
BUT, online on my website it's not.

language: PHP
CMS: Joomla

any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that :

Restricting api.twitter.com to SSL/TLS traffic
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239

I'm still not sure, I will test it when I have SSL server.